# ARC Semantic Issue: "No visible @interface for UIImageView" and PFImageView Semantic Issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, semantics, semantic-ui

I have a profileviewcontroller where these image views come about in order to fetch the profile picture mainly. But at the start of my profileviewController.m it is declaring "unknown type name 'PFImageView'; did you mean 'UIImageview'?" For the following line:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) PFImageView *imageUser;
```

I get the same exact one if the user were to add his profile pic:

```
-(void)addProfilePic
{
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    imageUser = [[PFImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width-100)/2, 50, 100, 100)];
```

I don't want to necessarily change to UIImageView thinking it might mess up something else within the code so was wondering on a clarification. Also I have a ARC Semantic Issue involving "No visible @interface for 'UIImageView' declares the selector 'setFile.'" and "No visible @interface for 'UIImageView' declares the selector 'loadInBackground.'" This is within my call on getting the profile picture:

```
-(void)getProfilePicture
{
    PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
    NSLog(@"file--%@",[user objectForKey:PF_USER_PICTURE]);

    userName = user[PF_USER_USERNAME];
    status = user[PF_USER_STATUS];

    if ([user objectForKey:PF_USER_PICTURE]) {
        [imageUser setFile:[user objectForKey:PF_USER_PICTURE]];
        [imageUser loadInBackground];
    }
    else{
        imageUser.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blank_profile@2x.png"];
    }


//    fieldName.text = user[PF_USER_FULLNAME];
}
```

The help is much appreciated, thanks for the time guys.

Comment: have u imported the required header file?

Comment: thanks for the help, appreciate it and yes its fixed now I'm on to my next error

Answer (score 1):

Import ParseUI FrameWork into your Project.

```
#import <ParseUI/ParseUI.h>
```

Import the above line into your header file where you want to use PFImageView

Comment: Thanks man ! I didn't notice that Parse has a new framework other than Parse/Parse.h

Answer (score 0):

The `unknown type` is telling you that your code doesn't yet have a reference to the file that defines `PDFImageView`.

Most likely, you are missing a line like `#import "PFImageView.h"` (or you may need to import a framework that contains the `PFImageView` header)

For now, Xcode is suggesting `UIImageView` it its place because UIKit must already be imported somewhere, and that is the closest class name to `PFImageView` that it can find in its scope.

Once you have imported the header file, assuming it exposes the method `loadInBackground`, your second error should disappear.